# Background Color animation doesn't display on <tr>

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a weird problem, I try to make an animation on a `tr` and it doesn't execute on a specific page.

I use this twice, it worked on a page and didn't on the second, the script is almost the same (parent change because of the DOM structure)

```
 $("#ajax button.delete").on("click", function(){
    var name = this.name,
        value= this.value;
        var parent = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'get',
          url: 'deleteCategory.php',
          data: 'delete=' + $(this).val(),
          beforeSend: function() {
            $('td', parent).animate({"background-color":'#fb6c6c'}, 300);
          },
          success: function() {
            parent.remove();
          }
        });
  });
```

In the script the parent variable is for the `tr` tag.

And a `tr` tag is filled with this :

```
 <tr>
    <td><span id="tcat{$data->cid}">{$data->name}</span>
        <div class="btn-group pull-right">
            <button id="ecat{$data->cid}" name="category" value="{$data->cid}" class="edit btn"><i class="icon-edit"></i> Modifier</button>
            <button id="dcat{$data->cid}" name="category" value="{$data->cid}" class="delete btn btn-danger"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Supprimer</button>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

So in fact the animation is not displayed and the remove() is done immediately.

Comment: Can you use jsfiddle.net to describe your code ?

Comment: Can't you simply move the animation before your ajax call? The beforeSend method is a pre-request call back. Since there is no callback that you perform, the call gets executed immediately

Comment: Here's a sample code with jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/NXEj2/

Comment: @Yeronimo the problem is the animation is not working, with ajax or not, as you can see in the jsfiddle. And it already worked with the ajax function in another page

Comment: I updated your fiddle to work. Mainly added jquery and jquery ui (for color animation) and changed your selector: http://jsfiddle.net/NXEj2/3/ Hope it can help you

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I still don't understand why it's working with the other page. I'm going to check the UI thing

Comment: I found the problem, A jquery plugin was not included into the source :/